# Minimum of |z|+|z-cos a -i sin a|...

Tags: complex-numbers

For a complex number $z$, the minimum value of $|z|+|z-\cos(a)-\iota \sin(a)|$ is:

$A. 0$

$B. 1$

$C. 2$

$D.$ None of these

The answer is option $B$. I see that the given expression is the sum of distances of $z$ from the origin and a general point on the circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$. But shouldn't the answer depend on $z$ ? Please help...

Comment: I think what the question should have said: what is the minimal value that $|z|+|z-\cos(a)-\iota \sin(a)|$ can take over all complex numbers $z$.  The way the question is written, I think you are correct.

Comment: May go through  http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z= x+iy$, Then $\left|z\right| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\left|z-\cos \alpha -i\sin \alpha\right| = \sqrt{(x-\cos \alpha)^2+(y-\sin \alpha)^2}$

So we have to minimize $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-\cos \alpha)^2+(y-\sin \alpha)^2}$

Now Using minkowski inequality Inequality, $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}\geq \sqrt{(a+b)^2+(c+d)^2}$

and equality holds when $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$

So $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(\cos \alpha-x)^2+(\sin \alpha-y)^2}\geq \sqrt{(x+\cos \alpha -x)^2+(y-\sin \alpha-y)^2} = 1$

and equality holds when $\displaystyle \frac{x}{y} = \frac{\cos \alpha - x}{\sin \alpha - y}$

Answer (score 2):

By triangle inequality $1=|\cos{a}+i\sin{a}-z+z| \le |z|+|z-\cos(a)-i\sin(a)|$

Comment: I think you have used the inequality incorrectly..

Comment: @Apurv. Why do you think so?.

Comment: Why the downvote ?.

Comment: It is $|z_1|+|z_2|>=|z_1 +z_2|$ and I suppose you have written $|z_1|+|z_2|>=|z_1 -z_2|$. Maybe I am wrong..

Comment: @Apurv. Okay you are telling that $|z_1|+|z_2|>=|z_1 +z_2|$ holds for every complex number $z_1$ and $z_2$. And I am applying it for the complex number $z_1$ and $-z_2$ and note that $|z|=|-z|$ to arrive in the second inequality. Isn't it clear?.

Comment: Oh sorry.. thanks !!

Comment: @Apurv. That's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=e^{ia}$ be any point on the unit circle. Now, for any point $z$ in the complex plane, we have as vectors

> $$ w=z+(z-w) \implies |w|=|z+(z-w)| \implies 1\leq |z|+|z-w| $$.